# What does the @ mean in URLs?

Tags: google-maps, url

I noticed in webpages such as Google maps there is an `@` in the URL. What does it do? For example https://www.google.com/maps/place/Vancouver+City+Hall/@49.260404,-123.113799,3a,75y,349.48h,90t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sUeoHwwwaQPVvyH1amrQAAQ!2e0!4m9!1m6!2m5!1sgoogle+maps+vancouver+city+hall!3m3!1scity+hall!2sVancouver,+BC,+Canada!3s0x548673f143a94fb3:0xbb9196ea9b81f38b!3m1!1s0x548673e7b8d4609d:0x9823432c0c571e10!6m1!1e1

Comment: I doubt that does anything special. It just "looks good" for a Maps URL I guess, using the *at* symbol to indicate a *location*. If it were an `@` at the *beginning* of a URL as in `http://user:pass@mysite.com`, then it would separate the authentication part from the host part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An URL in general is not consistenly consisting of directories followed by a file. Before it eventually beeing a physical directory+path, it's just a string, not more, not less. There is only 1 real special character in URL that is not part of this URI string: `#` (Hash fragment identifier).

Basically you can map any string after `//yourdomain.com/` (and before `#`) to anything you want.

Therefore, the `@` character in the URL only has cosmetical/optical/ however you call it meaning.

The `?` and `&` have a special meaning in terms of, the server can use these symbols to identify parameters. But it does not have to do so. It is in fact possible to map an URI like `//yourdomain.com/&&&` to a **complete** different resource than `//yourdomain.com/&&`.